# Binding XML to ModelViewControl

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want the method of a command to be in the ViewModel class, but the class is not finding it and it is showing this error.
what can i do to make it work

Github: https://github.com/IagoAntunes/FashionShop/tree/master/LojaRoupas/LojaRoupas

error:
No property ,BindableProperty or event found for "SearchButtonPressed", or mismatching type between value and property

SHOP.XML

```
SearchButtonPressed="{Binding PesquisarButton}" TextChanged="{Binding Pesquisar}"
```

```
<SearchBar Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="-5,10,0,10" BackgroundColor="Transparent" SearchButtonPressed="{Binding PesquisarButton}" TextChanged="{Binding Pesquisar}"/>
```

SHOP.cs

```
BindingContext = new ViewModel.ShopViewModel();
```

SHOPVIEWMODEL.cs

Here I have the method that will execute that command

```
public class ShopViewModel
{
        private void PesquisarButton(object sender,EventArgs args)
        {
            var Resultado = ListaRoupas.Where((b)=>b.Nome.Contains(((SearchBar)sender).Text)).ToList<Roupa>();
            Preencher(Resultado);
        }
        private void Pesquisar(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var Resultado = ListaRoupas.Where((b) => b.Nome.Contains(((SearchBar)sender).Text)).ToList<Roupa>();
            Preencher(Resultado);
        }
}
```

obs:I'm just showing the essential parts of the code

Comment: you need to make  PesquisarButton properties with getter and setter

Comment: you can only bind to **public properties**.  I also don't believe you can bind event handlers - you need to use the `SearchCommand` property if you want to use binding

Comment: but if i do that i lose the (sender,args) , or not?

Comment: You need to use Commands which acts like Event and Need to use Commandparameter for Passing Data to command like event args

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind text with the ViewModel property and then when the user clicks the search button you can get a text from that property.

please refer this official doc

[Xamarin.Forms SearchBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/searchbar)

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchButtonPressed="{Binding PesquisarButton}" TextChanged="{Binding Pesquisar}"
```

Change to

```
SearchCommand="{Binding PesquisarButton}" Text="{Binding Pesquisar, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

```
public class ShopViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
       public Command PesquisarButton => new Command(() =>
       {
            var Resultado = ListaRoupas.Where((b)=>b.Nome.Contains(Pesquisar).ToList<Roupa>();
            Preencher(Resultado);
        }

       public string Pesquisar{get;set;}

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs((propertyName)));
        }
}
```

Comment: It should be `SearchCommand` not `SearchButtonCommand` , check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/searchbar#perform-a-search-using-a-viewmodel .

Comment: And in this way the binding mode for `Text` should `TwoWay` .

Comment: Cool... edited! Isn't TwoWay by default tho?

Comment: No， `OneWay` is the default .